# Spring/Gradle - servlet-api dependency issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

still quite new to Gradle in general so hopefully this isn't a silly question, but I'm running into this issue when running the container (which immediately crashes the container).

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1319)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'

The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/app/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/lib/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext: file:/app/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

I have tried adding

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: '', module: 'servlet-api'
}
```

But it looks to remove the other version of the servlet api (the error specifies it is looking in servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar, but it removed the servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar, because the error output after building and running is now:

```
The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/app/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/lib/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext: file:/app/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar
```

I have run a dependency task and the servlet-api is dependant on org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1

What's the best way to go about solving this issue? I have tried excluding and giving the exact  version number, but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried adding in a newer version of the hadoop core dependency (that would come bundled with a newer version of the servlet-api. as I believe I need 3.1+ (I have 2.5)), but that also didn't seem to work

Comment: Why do you even have those dependencies on the classpath? THe only one should be from tomcat. Please add your dependencies to the question (your gradle build file).

Answer (score 1):

I think the error

> The following method did not exist:
>
> ```
> 'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'
> ```

is because the version of your servlet API is older than 3.1 and the method getVirtualServerName() was introduced in 3.1 and later versions.